# Can we add tag-specific info to the question page?

Tags: feature-request

I'm sure other tags have similar problems, but to provide a specific example:

In C# we get a lot of GUI questions. The problem is, there are 3 main GUI technologies that all have similar controls (WPF, ASP.NET, and WinForms) and the answer to a given question varies enormously depending on which is used. Of course, askers rarely specify which they are actually using.

If we could add a notification to the question area that said (when a question was tagged C#):

> We noticed you are asking a C# question! Please check the following for extra information answerers may need!

And then we would have something like (for C#):

> Is this question related to a GUI? If so, make sure to tag the display technology you are using (WPF, Winforms, ASP)!

Clearly other information/questions could be here as well.

Perhaps editing this "pre-post information" would be a "gold-badge" ability. Obviously this won't fix the problem entirely, as not every (any?) user reads the help text, but perhaps this will help cut down on common "clarification" comments in various tags.

Comment: Only 3?  Hahaha.  There are a half dozen incompatible dialects of "XAML" alone

Comment: @RobertLevy, We don't want to confuse them too much :) I'll take whatever information I can get.

Comment: I think you might be the first person to suggest this who hasn't [included Clippy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178367/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips). Has he finally retired?

Comment: @CodyGray, Never even thought of Clippy, I guess he has :)

Comment: We could use something like this for the sql tag -- the first comment is almost always "What RDBMS are you using?"

Comment: We could use this feature a lot. Form my tech, I'd like to ask for platform info, HTTP traffic captures, and other information. A lot of people don't know what information they need to provide in order to get help from other people. I really like how GitHub has issue and pull request templates. I think optional post templates provided by tag experts might be helpful. I find that post quality goes up when folks follow the templates.