# Can we get a tag post template mechanism?

Tags: feature-request

GitHub has issue and pull request templates. They've become very useful in improving the quality of the content in the issues and pull requests for our repos. I'd like to be able to provide **optional** post template guidance to posters to the tags I work. I end up asking the same clarifying questions over time and would like to front load those questions to when the POST is being constructed.

I did something like [this years ago as a forum moderator](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/77c07b69-eea6-43ab-9225-4b384cecfc9d/exchange-development-forum-guide-read-before-posting?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) and I did see an improvement in the content of forum post bodies and titles.

This would be especially useful for Stack Overflow for Enterprise.

I imagine a feature that lets the poster apply tag based markdown templates to their post from a drop down box.

This is related to [Can we add tag-specific info to the question page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258573/can-we-add-tag-specific-info-to-the-question-page).

Comment: By "tag post template", do you mean applying a question based on the selected tag(s)?

Comment: This is a really neat idea!

Comment: There's a *lot* of potential value here, but the idea also worries me. Much of what I and some of the other Meta denizens spend our time in Meta doing is just re-iterating, over and over again, that *no, not every question has to be a debugging question, dammit*
 - see [Tiny Giant's complaints on the recent template trial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/1709587#comment555505_363051). Winning that fight *once*, for the whole site, is already hard enough. I fear that, done wrongly, this could result in a proliferation of debugging-only templates that we won't be able to control.

Comment: (To be clear - I know you've emphasised **optional** in your proposal and that you're not asserting that the templates should be debugging-specific. I'm just saying that those details really matter; while this is a promising idea, it only takes a small deviation from the original vision to get into clearly-harmful territory, and the recent site-wide debugging-specific template trial doesn't exactly inspire certainty that the dev team would get this right.)

Comment: In the current UI, this would be kind of strange, as the tags are under the body, and I've always typed up the question first, and added the tags later. If we would add such a feature, users should enter their tags before writing the question.

Comment: I suggest that all readers of this post re-direct themselves to [Ask a question template v1 experiment results
](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363051/ask-a-question-template-v1-experiment-results).

Comment: I totally understand how this could turn a template feature into a debugging template feature and how that could have a dramatic impact on the SO post landscape. In my head that would be one of the primary uses. I bet there is a SO post categorization: how do I, what am I doing wrong, which choice do I make, etc.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yeah, I have the same pattern - that is, I add the tags after I write the body. I'd wager most folks do the same.

Comment: @MichaelMainer *"I bet there is a SO post categorization: how do I, what am I doing wrong, which choice do I make, etc"* - Yeah, I had the same thought over at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346347/guidance-for-writing-question#comment461742_346347, where I called them "question paradigms". I think that any non-harmful question template implementation that Stack Overflow comes up with is ultimately going to require a category selector or paradigm selector or whatever we want to call it.

Comment: @MarkAmery, thanks for the link to that post. "Question paradigm" nails what I'd like to see.